# jquery Mobile: check if checkbox is checked or not

Tags: jquery-mobile

How to check if checkbox is selected or not in jMobile using js?

```
<input class="custom" id="myCheckbox" name="myCheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Short:

```
$("#myCheckbox").is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is checked you can use

```
if( $("#myCheckbox").is(':checked'));
```

And if it is NOT checked you can use

```
if( $("#myCheckbox").not(':checked'));
```